# Upload images to the database and retrieve upon user request in Android (via PHP)

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, upload

I am trying to upload an image to the **MySQL** database in **android**(via **PHP**) and retrieve it upon user request. I searched everywhere but I still couldn't find an answer on how to do it. I am new to Android and would really appreciate it if you could help me. Please tell me a method to **upload images to MySQL** and retrieve only the requested images. I don't mind using *URLs* too. Thank you

Comment: You need to see webservices

Comment: what you have tried?show your code

Comment: @shammon I have not started anything yet because I don't know how to even start it

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using java. I have not much knowledge of PHP so I am providing you my java code to you. I hope you are able to convert it in PHP.

I am converting image to byte[] and passing byte[] in json string using http request to my RESTful web service. In service I am storing whole array in mysql blob. below is my code to store image in blob using JDBC connection.

```
final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(ImageArray, ImageArray.length);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

I hope this will help you.